# Negating a pattern in gitignore isn't working

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a top level .gitignore that ignores files with 'txt' extension--the pattern I'm using is `*.txt`.

I have a number of subdirectories that have '.txt' files that I want to commit, while still keeping the general restriction in place.

I have tried putting the following negated patterns in various instances of .gitignore; in each directory, in a higher directory that contain those directories, and in the top level for the repository. None of them work.

```
!*.txt
!doc/*.txt
!**/doc/*.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: I should note that I'm having this problem with GitForWindows as well as a standard git install on linux. This is my top level `.gitignore` file.

```
auth/*
systemlock/*
work/*
.project
.classpath

*.txt

# Allow vim plugin doc files
# GAHH! Why isn't this working?!!??1!!
#!**/docs?/*.txt
#!docs?/*.txt
#!docs?/*.txt
#!doc/*.txt

*~
*.log
*.tar
*.tar.gz
.*.sw[a-z]
*.WIP
.nfs*

# Security files should not be stored in a repository
authfile*
.authfile*

run.out
```

The path to the doc directories I'm trying to include do **not** include the words `auth`, `systemlock` or `work`.

I tried the commented patterns in a `.gitignore` file in the directory immediately above the files I want to unignore, but had the same problem. The path to that location, relative to the top level, is `dotfiles/.vim/bundle`.

Comment: Is git already tracking the txt files?

Comment: Can we see the entire `.gitignore`? The answer very much depends on the order of rules in `.gitignore`: unignore rules must go after ignore.

Comment: @evolutionxbox , no, git is not tracking those files.

Comment: @phd, .gitignore added to my question

Comment: `git ls-files -oc | git check-ignore -v --stdin` will tell you exactly why every file git can see is ignored or not .

Comment: For what it's worth, `docs?` in glob expressions matches strings like `docs1`, `docsa`, `docs=`, and the like: `?` is not a regular-expression "previous lexeme is optional" marker, it's much more like `.` in regular expressions. But `!**/doc/*.txt` seems like it should do the trick. Use the `git check-ignore -v` trick to find out why it's not.

Comment: @torek, that was the issue. Thank you.